# DataGridView with data source reports two different CurrentCellAddress row values

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I have a `DataGridView` with a `DataTable` as a `DataSource`, a `Label` that displays the currently selected cells address in the `DataGridView` and finally there is a `Button` that button opens a `MessageBox` to display the same currently selected cell address.

The label’s text is update in the `DataGridViews` `CellClick` event.

Using the picture below as an example: When the last “NewRow” is selected, the label will be updated correctly with the correct row five (5) index. However, when I click on the button and display the same selected cell address, the row index is four (4).

I am guessing this is has something to do with the `DataSource/DataTable` since this does NOT happen if the `DataGridView` is NOT bound to a data source.

[image]

I have a workaround for this, however I am not understanding why the same method `dataGridView1.CurrentCellAddress` appears to be returning incorrect/different values. What is going on from the time the method `CurrentCellAddress` is called in the cell click event and the same method is called later when the button is clicked? The selection has NOT changed yet it appears they are different numbers.  Thanks for any help.

Code I am using to test this…

```
DataTable gridData;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  //FillGrid();
  gridData = GetTable();
  FillDT(gridData);
  dataGridView1.DataSource = gridData;
  label1.Text = "CurrentCellAddress: " + dataGridView1.CurrentCellAddress.ToString();
}

private DataTable GetTable() {
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("Col1", typeof(String));
  dt.Columns.Add("Col2", typeof(String));
  dt.Columns.Add("Col3", typeof(String));
  return dt;
}

private void FillDT(DataTable dt) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    dt.Rows.Add("R" + i + "C1", "R" + i + "C2", "R" + i + "C3");
  }
}

private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
  label1.Text = "CurrentCellAddress: " + dataGridView1.CurrentCellAddress.ToString();
}

private void btnGetCellAddress_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  MessageBox.Show("CurrentCellAddress: " + dataGridView1.CurrentCellAddress.ToString(),"Cell Address");
}

// Method to fill the grid to show the values are correct 
// when the datagridview is not data bound
private void FillGrid() {
  dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn());
  dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn());
  dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn());
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add("R" + i + "C1", "R" + i + "C2", "R" + i + "C3");
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not clear because I am confused. Sound familiar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When focus of the `DataGridView` control is lost the `OnValidating` method ([source reference](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewMethods.cs,207aac0c0c4d5ba8)) is eventually called, which contains the following code:

```
// Current cell needs to be moved to the row just above the 'new row' if possible.
int rowIndex = this.Rows.GetPreviousRow(this.ptCurrentCell.Y, DataGridViewElementStates.Visible);
```

Selecting cells within the `DataGridView` keeps focus on the control, so this is never called. However, when using the button the focus is lost and `OnValidating` will move the current cell one row above the empty new row.

Comment: You are correct. The link in the answer also explains why the value returns correctly if there is NOT a data source. The first condition in the large if statement in the `OnRowValidated` reference you linked to is `if (this.DataSource != null &&`….. This definitely appears to explain what is going on. Thank You for the for the insightful clarification.